# DICAS DE PORTUGOL ENTRE "SE/SENAO", e "ESCOLHA/CASO"

Tags: portugol

Estou começando na programação e foi me passado um exercicio no curso para fazer um programa que leia nome, sexo e o valor das compras do cliente e calcule o preço com desconto. Sabendo
que:

- Homens ganham 5% de desconto
- Mulheres ganham 13% de desconto

Ate ae BLZ

AGR Q ENTRA MINHA DUVIDA

consegui fazer o codigo com as duas opcoes SE/SENAO e ESCOLHA/CASO

gostaria de saber qual mais aconselhavel para a situação?

Segue codigo usando a Expressao SE/SENAO

```
**algoritmo "23"
var
   nome:caractere
   valor,desconto,sexo:Real
inicio
      Escreva("Digite seu nome: ")
      leia(nome)
      Escreval("Digite seu sexo: ")
      Escreval("1 - HOMEM")
      Escreval("2 - MULHER")
      leia(sexo)
      EscrevaL("Qual o valor total das compras?: R$")
      leia(valor)
      Se (sexo)=1 entao
         desconto<-valor-valor*5/100
         Escreva("O valor total é de: R$",desconto)
      SeNao
           Se (sexo)=2 entao
              desconto<-valor-valor*13/100
              Escreva("O valor total é de: R$", desconto)
           SeNao
           FimSe
      FimSe
fimalgoritmo**
```

AGR segue codigo usando a expressao ESCOLHA/CASO

```
algoritmo "23"
var
   nome:caractere
   valor,desconto,sexo:Real
inicio
      Escreva("Digite seu nome: ")
      leia(nome)
      Escreval("Digite seu sexo: ")
      Escreval("1 - HOMEM")
      Escreval("2 - MULHER")
      leia(sexo)
      EscrevaL("Qual o valor total das compras?: R$")
      leia(valor)
      Escolha sexo
              Caso 1
                   desconto<-valor-valor*5/100
                   Escreval("Sua compra ficou: R$", desconto)
              Caso 2
                   desconto<-valor-valor*13/100
                   Escreval("Sua comprar ficou: RS", desconto)
      FimEscolha




fimalgoritmo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na questão não se aplica qual dos dois você irá utilizar, ambas irão solucionar seu problema. A utilização do ESCOLHA/CASO é quando temos situações diferentes e queríamos utilizar um código mais entendível para não se utilizar muitos SE/SE NÃO. Em determinadas linguagens de programação é de interesse saber de como se funciona na parte do Hardware, porém pelo que você relatou ainda está iniciando seus estudos.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, e vlw pela informação!